# why do we need to call current class in override method in django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, overriding

I am new to Django. I just move from c++. I have a question when I want to override a class method. Why do we need to call the current class name? for example

```
class MyStuff( models.Model ):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyStuff, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  #calling super "MyStuff" instead of "Model"
```

I am not sure how does Django work deep inside. Why don't we call `super(Model, self)`?  How can I call Grandparent method?

Comment: Your question is about python, not django. and this isn't a class method.

Comment: The canonical guide to `super` (link taken from Python's official docs): [Python’s super() considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576183/2108339)

when you do `super(MyStuff, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` you are calling a instance method of the 'parent'

In python, you have multiple inherance, so when you call super(), the Method Resolution Order is not to just one parent, because you have multiples parents.
See [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

hope helps

Comment: Oh yep. thanks. I want to vote u up but my reputation is less than 15